# How to read a file with delimiters

Tags: java, file

If I have a file like this, in which each section is delimited by "**". How can I read each section and put them into different data structures?

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
**
ccc:cc
ddd:dd
**
xyz;XYZ
abc;ABC
**

Name: John
Email: john@gmail.com

Name: Jack
Email: jack@gmail.com

Name: kate
Email: kake@hotmail.com
**
```

In a while loop, I can test whether the line equals "**". But since the number of lines in each section is unknown, it seems hard to recognize which section a particular line belongs to?

```
String line;
 while((line=reader.readline()) != null){

   if(!line.equals("**"){
      // the line has to be parsed and built into different data structures.
         For the first section, AAA,BBB,CCC will be added into an ArrayList.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried for better answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use a Scanner, setting the delimeter to whatever you want. I don't use scanner much anymore, not 100% sure, which is why this is a comment.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: _Can you explain more? what are you trying to achieve??_

Comment: For instance, for first section, I need to store those lines into an ArrayList, for second section, I need to parse each line and store them into another data structure, i.e. DataB, and likewise, DataC to store content for section 3.

Comment: Is it possible to have *any* valid data in a section to start, and if so, start or end with `*`?

Comment: @user697911 check out my updated answer. It separates the input into seperate lists

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, what do you mean, please?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should just make the reading method a little bit more clever.

Here is an example (a kind of pseudo code, assuming you have a reader that does an actual IO):

```
void main() {
  List<List<String>> sections = ...
  while(reader.hasMoreDataToProcess()) {
     sections.add(processSection(reader));
  }
}


List<String> processSection(reader) {
  List<String> section = ...
  do {
     String line = reader.readLine();
     if(line.equals("**"))  { // end of section or whatever delimiter you have
         return section;
     }
     section.addLine(line);      
  }while(true);
}
```

Comment: Then you read everything into a list with all sections. Then what's the difference between those sections, which will lead to creation of different data storage.

Comment: Don' think so - each time processSection is called it returns a List<String> that denotes one section, you could maintain the class for it. I've slightly updated the pseudo code to reflect the comment. Now in "main" method section variable will contain a list of sections. The main point was to show an idea regardless the actual technical implementation though

Comment: This makes more sense to me. however, my actual file structure is even more complex. I updated. Please pay attention to the last section. I need to create a Person object for each Name & Email entry, and then push them into a list for section 3. Then, I can't always use List<String> as the data structure. Any further idea? Thanks

Comment: You should probably un-accept this considering it doesn't equal your delimiter.

Comment: Well, again, its only an illustration of idea, it doesn't even compile :) So I didn't really care about the actual delimiter - I've updated the answer so that the delimiter will be the same as described in the question. Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in a hurry, so pseudocode:

```
currentSection = []
sections = [currentSection]
for each line:
  if line is the separator:
    currentSection = []
    add currentSection to sections
  else:
    add line to currentSection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method of the string class in Java.

```
String string = "a-b,b-d,c-s,d-w,e-e,f-e";
String[] parts = string.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // a-b
String part2 = parts[1]; // b-d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use scanner for this scenario. Here's how you do it. This code is not tested.

```
File file = new File("somefile.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimeter("\\*\\*");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String s = sc.next();
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Scanner` with a `FileInputStream` to scan the file, using `setDelimiter(String)` (which accepts a regex pattern) to set your delimiter.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();

        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("yourFile.txt"))).useDelimiter("[*]+")) {
            firstList.add(scanner.next());
                    secondList.add(scanner.next());
                    // and so on

            scanner.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

This will take everything above `**` and create a String out of it. If you want, you can then split the String, and  grab the data from each line.

```
String[] split = scanner.next().split("\n");
for(String string : split) {
     firstList.add(string);
}
```

In the first example, the regex `[*]+` searches for multiple `*`. Learn more about regex (regular expressions) to add flexibility.